# Pointer to an array of structure in C

Tags: c

I have a requirement to use pointer to a array of structures as defined below:

```
typedef void (*fptr)(uint8 arg);
typedef struct sTest
{
  uint8 u8Mem1;
  uint8 u8Mem2;
  fptr fptr1;
}tTest;
```

Now I have define an array of this structre as follow:

```
tTest sTestStructure[20];
```

So now I want define a pointer and assign the array of stuct{sTestStructure[20]} to this pointer.Then access the member of this structure using the pointer define.
So please let me know how can I define this pointer and also how to access the members using pointer.

Comment: you can use pointet *ptrsturct that is     tTest *ptstruct = sTestStructure;

Comment: Your two choices are to use a pointer to first element (just write `sTestStructure`) or pointer to array `&sTestStructure` which has type `tTest (*)[20]`.  The first choice is *far* more common in C.

Comment: tTest** ptr = &sTestStructure ? (litterally a pointer to an array of your structure)

Comment: @Fefux: wrong type - the expression `&sTestStructure` has type `tTest (*)[20]`, not `tTest **`.

Comment: Yes, my comment is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" (`T [N]`) will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" (`T *`), and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

This naturally leads us to the following:

```
tTest *ptr = sTestStructure;  // note no & operator!
```

The *expression* `sTestStructure` is implicitly converted from type "20-element array of `tTest`" to "pointer to `tTest`", and the value of the expression is the same as `&sTestStructure[0]`.  To access any element of `sTestStructure`, you could simply index into `ptr` as you would `sTestStructure`:

```
ptr[i].u8Mem1 = some_value;                // sTestStructure[i].u8Mem1 = some_value
printf( "%" PRIu8 "\n", ptr[j].u8Mem2 );
```

Remember that the subscript operation `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)`; given the address `a`, offset `i` *elements* from that address and defereference the result.  Thus, the `[]` operator implicitly dereferences `ptr`, which is why we use the `.` operator to access each struct member.

Alternately, you could also access struct members using the `->` operator, and advance the pointer as necessary:

```
tTest *ptr = sTestStructure;
while( ptr->u8Mem1 != some_value )  // no subscript operation here
  ptr++;
```

The expression `ptr->u8Mem1` is equivalent to `(*ptr).u8Mem1`<sup>1</sup>, which is equivalent to `ptr[0].u8Mem1`.

So what happens if we decide to use `&sTestStructure` instead?  Since `sTestStructure` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, the conversion rule above doesn't apply; instead of getting a pointer to a pointer to `tTest`, we get a pointer to a *20-element array* of `tTest`, or:

```
tTest (*arrPtr)[20] = &sTestStructure;
```

This presents a bit more of a challenge, since we have to dereference `arrPtr` *before* we can index into it:

```
(*arrPtr)[i].u8Mem1 = some_value;
printf( "%" PRIu8 "\n", (*arrPtr)[j].u8Mem2 );
```

Since `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`, the expression `*arrPtr` can also be written as `arrPtr[0]` (`*arrPtr == *(arrPtr + 0) == arrPtr[0]`).  So those 
lines could also be written as

```
arrPtr[0][i].u8Mem1 = some_value;
printf( "%" PRIu8 "\n", arrPtr[0][j].u8Mem2 );
```

As should be evident from those last couple of lines, you normally don't see this form of an array pointer unless you're dealing with multi-dimensional arrays.  Remember our conversion rule, where an expression of type `T [N]` is converted to an expression of type `T *`?  Well, replace `T` with an array type like `Q[M]`, and we get the conversion from "N-element array of M-element array of `Q`" (`Q [N][M]`) to "pointer to M-element array of `Q`" (`Q (*)[M]`):

```
tTest sTestStructure[10][20];
tTest (*arrPtr)[20] = sTestStructure;
```

---

1. Postfix `.` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*ptr.u8Mem1` would be parsed as `*(ptr.u8Mem1)`, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

They already told you how to define the pointer, now if you want to access a property would be  *pointer->property.....